# How to set data for nested object's fields in drools decision table

Tags: java, drools, drools-fusion

I want to set data for nested object in drools decision table. I have a Java model class `SalesMobilityApiModel` in which I have a nested object of type `AddressProofModel`. The `AddressProofModel` class has few fields, such as `String documentCategory`, `String documentType`, etc.

Now I want to set values for the fields of the nested object, for example:

```
addressProofModel.setDocumentCategory("category1")
```

based on condition of one of the input parameter 'profile' in the parent `SalesMobilityApiModel` object.

I using Drools decision tables and can't figure out how to do this.

[image: SalesMobilityApiModel]
[image: AddressProofModel]

I have tried multiple things to set values for the fields inside the nested class 'AddressProofModel', but every time faced some exception.

[image: Solution attempt]

How can I update the fields in the child object?